# concatenate field names in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Could you please tell me how to change field name?

First, I query some data like this:

```
u = User.find_by_id(111)
```

It will provide a data like this:

```
u.id,u.foo,u.bar
```

But, I want to change a result to the below: ("name" is concatenation of u.foo+ u.bar)

```
u.id,u.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method in the `user` model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    self.foo + ' ' + self.bar
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! It's work. But I wonder that if there is a way to change the field name from sql side? just like select u.id, "u.foo + u.bar" as name from user u

Comment: You could, using `find_by_sql`, but would loose the benefits of `active_record`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `#` when joining two field with different datatypes.

For example, adding one integer and string with `+` will give an error.

So better use it this way.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    "#{foo} #{bar}"
  end
end
```

Hope the detail helps.

Comment: what is `foo` is nil?

Comment: It will print only `bar`

Comment: Yeah, I see, but the name will have an unexpected space!